# PHP Storm - Code helper not working for class which returns a class

Tags: phpstorm

I have a code like this:
(pseudo code)

```
class parent
{
   /** @var aChild */  // <---- this is the fix! that tells PHP Storm about the class, from now on it understands the chain.
   private $achild;
   // in constructor $achild is defined through a '$this->$achild = new aChild();'

   public method()
   {
      return $this->achild;
   }
}

class aChild extends parent
{
   public method_from_child($x)
   {
   }
}

 $parent->method()->method_from_child(123);
```

The code works fine like that, parent returns another class (which is a member of parent) and I can directly work with the public functions of that child class.
However, I was not able to get PHPStorm to understand that part.
The Code helper only works until $parent->method() but if I add another -> it only suggests one more $method.

Comment: Damn I was too fast asking the question.
adding before the private member declaration solved it.
/** @var aChild */

Comment: I recommend to add correct PHPDoc comments to other methods as well (with proper `@return` tag etc) -- more deterministic / failsafe this way.